# <%=HTMLEncode(rs("Notes"))%>, Error when Notes = Null

Tags: sql, database, asp-classic

I am pulling in motes from a table saved in my Microsoft access database, the database is very old and some forms have null notes values (the forms where created before the notes section was added). When I try to open the forms with null notes, the ASP classic webpage doesn't load, this it what im trying:

```vb
<%=HTMLEncode(rs("Notes"))%>
```

If I go into the DB and simply place a period in the notes the ASP webpage will open, I have thousands of forms so I cant do this one by one. I cant figure out how to get around this error, I have tried:

```vb
<%=HTMLEncode(rs("Notes") & ".")%>
```

This might be of value also,

```vb
Dim rs
Set rs = Server.Createobject("ADODB.Recordset")
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Did appending the period work? You'd also need to check the definition of the `HTMLEncode` function. (`Server.HTMLEncode` is a built-in function, but `HTMLEncode` is not)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try modifying your query - for example

```
SELECT MyCol1, MyCol2, ISNULL(Notes, '') AS Notes FROM MyTable
```

In this way, you guarantee that the query doesn't return NULL even if the underlying table contains NULL.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up just placing an <%On Error Resume Next%> command and it forced through whatever little hang-up was happening and its working now. probably not the best way to fix it but it works!

Comment: Ignoring the problem with Resume Next isn't going to help you in the long run. You should just check to see if the value is Null before you output it using IsNull().

Answer (score 1):

Use a function:

```
Function EncodeHTML(value)
    If IsNull(value) Then
        EncodeHTML = ""
    Else  
        EncodeHTML = HTMLEncode(value)
    End If
End Function
```

Then call it like this:

```
<%=EncodeHTML(rs("Notes"))%>
```